# Django Image Shows As A Error How TO Fix?

Tags: html, css, django

I did everythin you said but still getting this error could you show me where I went wrong?

made a folder called [static](https://gyazo.com/77c4f06b3e0e3933a63b064235f42b2d)

in my static folder made an image [folder](https://gyazo.com/8ff40ce13a556a0aabeefdcdfa637304)

in my image folder I put all my images [there](https://gyazo.com/817c2a6c7f10c3e67ecc936267cb8c61)

then went to my settings.py added [this](https://gyazo.com/4a7e3b8777c440745a6d04d3cbf50158)

in my templates my home page I did this [image](https://gyazo.com/3a38df77f981d7e8dce43e8fe9ac5840)

then changed the image attribute in my home page [image](https://gyazo.com/325986e6de088059961e736118d1d4e5)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I am still getting the error [image](https://gyazo.com/76e5256cdf06ddcce0f7f0d361b120f4)

Comment: Use static load and configure static file in setting.py

Comment: could you explain how I could do that I am learning django and still have much to learn

Comment: Read django static files doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/ . this might helps. btw thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is your problem and Django is your solution. follow the steps below to display your image,

- create a folder in your django project directory called static,
- create another folder inside of it called images,
- place your image in the images directory,
- in the end of your settings.py file, type this `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`,
- in the top of your html file, type `{% load static %}`,
- in the src attribute of your image, type `src="{% static 'images/paris.jpg' %}"`,

Comment: I updated the page to show the steps you have given me but I am getting the error could you please check and help me out a little more Thank YOu!

Answer (score 1):

add this to your settings file:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```